# replace single quotes with double quotes for string output

Tags: python

I have a function databricks written in pyspark which accepts to parameters and and the values passed to the function at as below:
values as below

```
stringa = "XYZ_ABC"
stringb = "ab"
```

function is as below

```
def pos(stringa,stringb):
    if stringb in stringa:
      return stringa
    else:
        return stringa    
  ab = pos(stringa,stringb)
```

the above fuction returns me an output as
'XYZ_ABC'
however the expected output is
"XYZ_ABC"

Comment: `'XYZ_ABC'` and `"XYZ_ABC"` represent the same `str` objects.

Comment: Single quotes, double quotes, tripple single quotes, tripple double quotes ... internally it's all the same string. If the console output really bothers you, format it as JSON.

Comment: @MikeScotty the reason beacuse we want the output in double quotes is because we have to pass the same output to a stored proc being called in databricks thats why we need the output in double quoted

Comment: The string doesn't actually contain the quotes, they're just printed that way because the console prints the same as `print(repr(stringa))`.  If you want quotes in the actual string you'll need to add them yourself, and you can add whichever style you like.

Answer (score 1):

String "XYZ_ABC" or """XYZ_ABC""" or 'XYZ_ABC' or '''XYZ_ABC''' are same.

If you still want to have output on console in double-quotes use this print("""+ab+""")

Comment: i dont want a print which is of nonetype..we want a return type with Str type

Answer (score 1):

The string doesn't actually contain the quotes, they're just printed that way because the console displays a variable the same as `print(repr(ab))`.  If you `print(ab)` you'll see the difference.

If you want quotes in the actual string you'll need to add them yourself, and you can add whichever style you like.

```
ab = '"' + pos(stringa,stringb) + '"'
```

Comment: now i have the output as '"XYZ_ABC"' with single quotes in it ..where as we need only "XYZ_ABC"

Comment: @batman_special read the whole answer, not just the last line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between using single or double-quoted strings. Both representations can be used interchangeably, so it has no sense to try to move from single to double-quotes.

If you write a double-quoted string in the console, you will see that the result is shown single-quoted.

```py
>>> "asd"
'asd'
```

Comment: @JoepJoestar the reason beacuse we want the output in double quotes is because we have to pass the same output to a stored proc being called in databricks thats why we need the output in double quoted

Comment: Then, extend your question and add the specific proc, the error that you are getting, etc...